# Hosting multiple games on a node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

im doing a project thats a website where you can go, find someone to play with and then the node js server will make a new insance of a game where you can play together. I have done the hosting games part where when 2 people connect, a new game will be made using the code below:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/game/:id', function (req, res)
{
    res.render('game', {game: req.params.id});
});
```

So that basicily makes a new page for the game with the url /game/2 for example

The problem im having is running multiple games on the same server, I dont know where or how to start. I recentlt done a snake game with node js where there was 1 game and mutliple people could join but how would i seperate multiple games? Im thinking of having a gamesList[] on the server to list all of the current games but where would the logic for every current game go?

If anyone could point me in the right direction, maybe if theres an open source example where someone has done the same thing, even if its just a simple tic tac toe that would be fantastic but i couldnt find anything like that. Any help is appriciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an object on your server would definitely do the trick. You can make an `app.gameLogic` object, with the `ids` as keys and whatever information you need to store as the value.

I'm not sure I understood the question perfectly, but I hope that helps.

Comment: but i mean if it was tic tac toe, there would be a function to see whos the winner. where would the logic like that go and how would i link everything up? i was hoping someone could point me an example or a video on how its done

Comment: So what you could do is have an object that  keeps track of the state on the server. If it was tic tac toe, you would have:

```
{
  GAME_ID: [[1,-1,0],[-1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
}
```

or something. And your players would send information like move_position to the server, along with what color they were, and the id of their game.

___

You would use that information to update the server's game-state. I would write a function that takes in the current state and the move made. Use the ID from the request to figure out which game on the server you're talking about and update it.

Comment: ohhhhh i think that makes sense. So client sends mouse position when clicked. then for each game, check to see what game that player is in, then once its got the id. Run a function like placeChecker(id, x, y) which then does the logic and puts the output back into the game object. Thats genius, thankyou very much i understand perfectly now :)